# Savefig as eps yields a non-usable eps

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I tried to save a plot in IPython as eps, it seems to work at first, but once I try to access the plot via latex or word it does not display anything. If I save the plot as png or jpg it works without problem. The problem occurs both with the command `savefig()` but also when I try to save the plot via ipython figure.

EDIT:
The problem occurs only when I use 'import seaborn', pure `matplotlib` actually works fine with eps!

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
path = 'D:\\'

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=True)

# Generate some sequential data
x = np.arange(60)
y1 = np.random.standard_normal(60)
f1 = sns.barplot(x, y1, palette="BuGn_d", ax=ax1)
ax1.set_ylabel("t-values")
ax1.set_xlabel("Lag $r_t$")
f1.text(35, 4, 'OLS: $\\frac{r_t}{\\sigma_{t-1}}= \\alpha +'
               '\\beta_{h} \\frac{r_{t-h}}{\\sigma_{t-h-1}} +'
               '\\epsilon_{t}$', fontsize=14)
y2 = np.random.standard_normal(60)
f2 = sns.barplot(x, y2, palette="RdBu_r", ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel("t-values")
ax2.set_xlabel("Lag $r_t$")
f2.text(35, 4, 'OLS: $\\frac{r_t}{\\sigma_{t-1}}= \\alpha +'
               '\\beta_{h} sign(r_{t-h}) + \\epsilon_{t}$', fontsize=14)

sns.despine(bottom=True)
plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[-3,-1,1,3,5])
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=3)
f.suptitle('t-values of lagged returns (Driscoll Kraay robust SE)')

f.savefig('\\'.join([path,'t_stats_robust.jpg']), format='jpg', dpi=1000,
          orientation='landscape')
f.savefig('\\'.join([path,'t_stats_robust.eps']), format='eps', dpi=1000,
          orientation='landscape')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mwe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a problem with figure embedding in LaTeX/Word? Can you open the figure in Photoshop/GIMP/Ghostscript etc.?

Comment: I have added the explicit problem as an example. I can't open the figure in GIMP, it raises an error (cannot interpret the file)

Comment: I just figured out the problem only occurs when I use `import seaborn` plotting pure `matplotlib` works as eps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to an issue in `matplotlib`. The ps and eps issues are related to a specification of rcParams when used on `win` os-systems. See the [github issue link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5862#issuecomment-197330145) for a quick fix and for tracking the bug fixing.